# Restangular with angular-http-auth not working

Tags: angularjs, restangular, angular-http-auth

I had been using [Angular-HTTP-Auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) with the basic http requests, but have since moved to Restangular and are now finding that 401's are no longer caught by HTTP-Auth.  I'm assuming this is because the Angular http methods aren't used or are intercepted somehow.  Is there a method for making these work together again?  I know that Restangular has interceptor's exposed, but I'm not certain how the 2 need to operate.